# Admob fillrate always 0%

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

i'm using admob for an app i just launched the other day, at first there were no downloads, but with a campaign i'm using now, i've gotten 140 requests yesterday and as of now, 44 and counting... but still, on the old admob website, it says that it isn't active because it has not yet received any ad request.

I have another app in the admob list, and it is showing on the old website as a green light.

I don't think there is anything wrong with my code, otherwise there wouldn't be any requests, am i right?

Thank you.

EDIT

Also: i couldn't find any contact to write to..

EDIT

P.S. test ads are showing on my smartphone and on the emulator..

EDIT

This is what is being shown to me of today:

```
Requests 299
Impressions 0
Fill Rate 0%
```

What should I do? Everything seems to be working the right way aside from 0 impressions and 0% fill rate...

i have a smart banner if that counts..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by archiving and creating a new banner in adMob. I had a 100% fill rate immediately. Perhaps it may help you...